How to implement URL Rewrite logic for CloudFront Functions
I'm looking to implement URI Rewrite Logic with Javascript with CloudFront functions.
Looking at many articles and it shows for all for URI Redirect. How can I implement this code (I'm all new to Javascript).
This is required to see how cloudfront making request to the origin (not looking for Lambda@Edge currently).
Trying with the logic, but not I'm able to make it work.
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    // Example rewrite rule: rewrite "/old-path" to "/new-path"
    if (uri.startsWith('/old-path')) {
        request.uri = uri.replace('/old-path', '/new-path');
    }

    // Return the modified request to CloudFront
    return request;
}


Can you elaborate more on what exactly you've tried and what isn't working? What errors are you seeing?
